# How to add a "Select all" option in Shiny

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

I am creating a questionnaire using shiny and shinydashboard. Using checkboxGroupInput(). I would like to have a select all option. I have seen other people have had similar issues, but I haven´t found a good solution yet. I would like to not use PickerInput because it does not look as nice

Here is the code. This version correctly select and deselect all options, but then it does not allow for clicking single boxes. Also my options are defined in the server, not the ui,, if that makes any difference.

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Questionnaire"),
  dashboardSidebar(collapsed = TRUE,
                   sidebarMenu(
                     id = "tabs",
                     menuItem("Page 1", tabName = "page1")
                   )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "page1",
              column(width = 12, offset = 3,
                     fluidRow(
                       box(
                         title = "",
                         subtitle = "",
                         checkboxGroupInput("species", "Select", choices = NULL, selected = NULL)
                       )
                     )
              )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "species", choices = c("Select all", 1:10),
                             selected = if ("Select all" %in% input$species) c("Select all", 1:10)
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I also tried this other server code. This allows to select single boxes, but it does not deselct all options once "Select all" is unclicked

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    if ("Select all" %in% input$species) {
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "species", choices = c("Select all", 1:10),
                               selected = c("Select all", 1:10))
    } else {
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "species", choices = c("Select all", 1:10),
                               selected = input$species)
    }
  })
}
```

Thanks to anyone that can somehow help me!

Comment: I know you mentioned that `pickerInput` doesn't look so nice but `shinyWidgets` has another function called `virtualSelectInput` which might be worth looking at. Try the demo `shinyWidgets::demoVirtualSelect()`

Comment: @EliBerkow Thanks, It actually looks good like this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the **reactCheckbox** package, which provides exactly the widget you want.

[image]

```r
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)
library(reactCheckbox)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  reactCheckboxesInput(
    "iris",
    list(
      checkbox("Sepal length", FALSE),
      checkbox("Sepal width", FALSE),
      checkbox("Petal length", FALSE),
      checkbox("Petal width", FALSE)
    ),
    headLabel = tags$span(
      "Make a choice", style = "font-size: 1.8rem; font-style: italic;"
    ),
    headClass = "custom",
    theme = "material",
    styles = list(
      "custom" = checkboxStyle(
        checked = css(
          background.color = "darkred"
        ),
        checked_hover = css(
          background.color = "maroon"
        ),
        unchecked = css(
          background.color = "darkorange"
        ),
        unchecked_hover = css(
          background.color = "orange"
        ),
        indeterminate = css(
          background.color = "gold"
        ),
        indeterminate_hover = css(
          background.color = "yellow"
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    print(input[["iris"]])
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks! It would be exactly what I need. I was looking at the documentation after your first comment, but I am having troubles to code it for my specific case. How do I deal with checkbox() when I have to define the list of possible answers in the server? (in my actual questionnaire the list of possible answers depends on previous responses and it can be super long)

Comment: @GiorgioZavattoni How would you with classical checkboxes? Can't you use `renderUI`?

Comment: I am confused because for example the function checkboxGroupInput() has an argument "choices", wheras checkbox() no and I cannot manually put single values everytime because they are automatically taken. It may be something easy that I am missing, this is the first time I am creating something with shiny.

Comment: @GiorgioZavattoni Try `mapply(checkbox, c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", ...), c(FALSE, TRUE, ...))`.

Comment: I am tryin for simplicity first in the UI, but still does no work. It shows just one box with no label ´ui <- fluidPage(
  reactCheckboxesInput(
    "iris", checkboxes = list(mapply(checkbox, c("1", "2", "3"), c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)))
  )
)`

Comment: @GiorgioZavattoni Not `list(mapply`, just `mapply`.

Comment: Without list() it gives this error: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : subscript out of bounds

Comment: @GiorgioZavattoni Hmm did you try with the option `SIMPLIFY = FALSE` ? Please try and I will work on it if that still does not work.

Comment: If I do that it does not produce an error anymore, but when I ran the app it just shows a blank page, it does not show neither the option list or the headlabel

Comment: @GiorgioZavattoni I've tried. One also has to set the option `USE.NAMES = FALSE`.